# Torch - narrow() without memory copy

Tags: torch

Is there any way of using `:narrow` in place and avoiding having to make a copy? I.e. `:resize` is the in place version of `:reshape`, is there an equivalent for narrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs, [`narrow`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/02fb5bdbc3909f8c1c7f854fe2f7b294ff8064ea/doc/tensor.md#extracting-sub-tensors) does not perform a memory copy:

> For methods `narrow`, `select` and `sub` the returned tensor shares the same `Storage` as the original. Hence, any modification in the memory of the sub-tensor will have an impact on the primary tensor, and vice-versa. These methods are very fast, as **they do not involve any memory copy**.

Example:

```
th> x = torch.Tensor{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

th> y = x:narrow(1, 2, 1)

th> print(x:storage():data())
cdata<double *>: 0x0079f240

th> print(y:storage():data())
cdata<double *>: 0x0079f240
```

They only return a new tensor, i.e. a new *object* that uses the same storage behind the scenes.

If you really want to modify the original tensor in-place you can use [`set`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/02fb5bdbc3909f8c1c7f854fe2f7b294ff8064ea/doc/tensor.md#self-settensor):

```
th> x:set(y)
 3  4
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x2]
```

Or even simpler `x = y`.